# Why can PHP still read/write to this locked file?

Tags: php, file-locking

I am having trouble understanding exactly how locked a `flock()`ed file is.  I am locking a simple text file like so:

```
// file_lock.php

$filename = "data.txt";
$delay = 5;

$lock = fopen($filename, "w");
if ($lock === FALSE || !flock($lock, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB, $block) || $block) {
    echo "ERROR:  Can not open or lock " . $filename . "\n";
    sleep($delay);
}
else {
    echo "SUCCESS: " . $filename . " locked.\n";
    sleep($delay);
    flock($lock, LOCK_UN);
    echo $filename . " unlocked\n";
}
```

Then, from another script, I check if the file `is_writable()` / `is_readable()` :

```
// test.php

$filename = "data.txt";

if (is_readable($filename)) echo "File is readable\n";
else echo "File is not readable\n";

if (is_writable($filename)) echo "File is writable\n";
else echo "File is not writable\n";
```

But when I run them, they both think they have access:

```
$ php file_lock.php & php test.php
SUCCESS: data.txt locked.
File is readable
File is writable
data.txt unlocked
```

The docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_is_readable.asp) are pretty scant on details, what am I missing?  Am I using flock incorrectly?  Do the functions `is_readable()` and `is_writable()` check something unrelated to determine read/writability?

Comment: Just curious, have you tried actually writing to the file in the test.php script?

Comment: Are readable/writable are IIRC purely permission checks, they don't check the lock status of a file?

Comment: @Tom I didn't try actually interacting with the file, I assumed it wouldn't work as the file _should_ be locked.

Comment: @Mark That didn't occur to me, I'll test that out.

Comment: is_readable()/is_writeable only checks the permissions on a file. You can't acquire a lock on a file or check its lock status without opening the file first.

Comment: Indeed, it would appear that `is_read/writeable()` merely checks permissions.  Time to get googling for another solution!

Answer (score 1):

The docs are missing a lot of details, but they do include one important detail on `is_readable()` or `is_writable()`:

> **Note:** The results of this function are cached. See [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)
>   for more details.

You'll need to run `clearstatcache()` against that file or directory before calling `is_readable()` to see up-to-date information.

Comment: Added this, same problem.  It appears to be a permission problem, as Mark guessed above.